# Title Image is not centered in the Toolbar

Tags: image, codenameone, toolbar, center, title

I was playing with the Netflix Clone App that was in one of the Codenameone Tutorials. I noticed in the simulator, the "Netflix" image title was not centered as expected according to the video:

[image: Title Image not Centered]

The code that is supposed to display the title is:

```
((Label)tb.getTitleComponent()).setIcon(r.getImage("netflix-logo.png"));
```

After invoking a deprecated method setAlignment:

```
Label title = (Label)tb.getTitleComponent();
title.setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
```

Now the title is displayed properly in the simulator:

[image: Title Image Centered]

Since the example was done a few years ago, can anyone tell me which is the correct way of centering an image title in the Toolbar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at [the code](https://github.com/shai-almog/NetflixCloneCN1) right now and can't find `setAlignment` there.

I don't think I would have used it. The right way to center a title is `tb.setTitleCentered(true);`.